# How to set up IIS server on FSx file system?

Tags: iis, autoscaling, amazon-fsx

I have an auto-scaling group configured with min/max value 1. When the instance fails, there are active calls that would be going on via the server. I want to set up IIS server on aws FSx file system that will act as a cache when my ec2 goes down, it will keep the information and pass to the newly created ec2 instance. Is it possible to set up?

Is there any better solution for this? Any good approach or alternative solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Auto Scaling group can automatically detect when an instance is unhealthy and replace it with a new one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-health-checks.html#replace-unhealthy-instance

Comment: How I am going to retrieve the IIS server cache when the instance is terminated.?